# how to wait the execution of line in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("#div_id").click(function() {
    $(this).effect("shake", { times:3 }, 300);
    // Here I want wait that the div_id can complete its shake
    alert('hello');
  }
```

.delay I tried but it is not working.

Comment: You need to use a *callback*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(this).effect("shake", { times:3 }, 300, function() {

    // this will alert once the animation has completed
    alert('hello');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery UI, you should just be able to add a callback as the 4th parameter.

See: http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/

```
$("#div_id").click(function() {
    $(this).effect("shake", { times:3 }, 300, function(){
        alert('hello');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).effect("shake", { times:3 }, 300, function() {
   alert('hello');
});
```